# How to tell if processing the last line of input in a Powershell cmdlet?

Tags: shell, powershell

I want to know how to test if I am currently processing the last line of input in a commandlet (this might not be the correct term) in Powershell.

I have a series of SQL statments in a log file and I want to construct an union of them. Currently I have (on one line, but I show them separated here for readability here)

```
echo "SELECT * FROM ( " > union.log
cat sql.log | %{$_ + "`n UNION `n"} >> union.log
echo " ) AS qwerty " >> union.log
```

However, this results in a superfluous `UNION` in the output. Therefore, I could like to test in the cmdlet (that's what I think the `%{...}` is called) if the current line is the last one and then not append the string "UNION".

Is this even possible?

---

**PS-** This is a simplified example, in my real case I have to do some grepping and substring to extract the  queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use the `-join` operator if you want to take a series of strings and merge them together with something between.

Eg.

```
@('a', 'b', 'c') -join ':'
```

results in `a:b:c`.

Comment: How do I use `join` when the input is coming in on standard in?

Comment: Like so - `(cat sql.log) -join "<backtick>nUNION<backtick>n"`.